# Entire git history of commits is doubled up

Tags: git, github

**Background**

I just noticed that the entire commit history in my repo is doubled up.

For reference, I am the sole contributor, and it's a private repository.

It will appear as if there are two contributors, because I have an old account, whose info was still in `git config --global user.email` on one of my computers.

The doubling-up occurred after I cloned the project and started working on it from another computer.

Excerpt from `git log`:

```
commit 76cd0efa307e501abfe13cd907957e4dcff7e75e
Author: myaccount <account1@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 21 18:58:39 2016 +0100

FEATURE - Add VideoNotFoundException.

commit 0430ef9dc5d3baa2189ba1c18b4bedb9d2940e51
Author: myaccount <account2@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 21 18:58:39 2016 +0100

FEATURE - Add VideoNotFoundException.

commit 94e7221e472e29119c9e4fe48944cd4d7528e207
Author: myaccount <account1@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 21 18:41:11 2016 +0100

FEATURE - Add previous/next video links to video view.

commit 8b26a51b84d4fb3ae72eefe2834649ff8bc8b7ce
Author: myaccount <account2@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 21 18:41:11 2016 +0100

FEATURE - Add previous/next video links to video view.

commit 7f9b3b6f214e445918d509d7f9377d3d7ce875da
Author: myaccount <account1@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Mar 15 17:05:46 2016 +0100

CLEANUP - Remove unused code/uses.

commit c83fa2c238d1437c967b40d6e807c2567eb7572d
Author: myaccount <account2@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Mar 15 17:05:46 2016 +0100

CLEANUP - Remove unused code/uses.
```

There are now 234 commits in the repository, of which about half are actual, real commits.

This is also reflected on GitHub:

[image]

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all however does NOT reflect this.

*   303bbfe (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) MERGE
|\  
| * b8052ce REFACTOR - Refactor front page content for maintainability.
| * b5907b2 VISUAL - Improve front page mobile view.
| * 0430ef9 FEATURE - Add VideoNotFoundException.
| * 8b26a51 FEATURE - Add previous/next video links to video view.
| * c83fa2c CLEANUP - Remove unused code/uses.
| * 9e82b8f BUGFIX - Fix redirecting /login to front page.
| * 491b88e BUGFIX - Redirecting old playlist and video links to new ones. WIP: Code duplication!
| *   a7da158 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/alrasch/UDLv2
| |\  
| | * a3bfe1b BUGFIX - Fix 500 error on 404 page.
| * | 258d2e9 BUGFIX - Redirecting old URLs to new ones.
| |/  
| * 4426681 FEATURE - Add more UDL logo assets.
| * 7d15c7c FEATURE - Add custom 404 page.
| * 6fbb5dd FEATURE - Add 'forgot password' function.
| * 92dd4c8 VISUAL - Fix video view layout.
| * 8a7decb VISUAL - Scale UDL logo to 75% on front page.
| * 0900fbc VISUAL - Rearrange discipline view layout.
| * 1ba38c8 VISUAL - Scale UDL logo on playlist view down to 75%.
| * eef7cd1 VISUAL - Fix playlist view layout.
| * b7fa6cb Made sidebar space on front page.
| * ace9fb6 COSMETIC - Logo on front page and navbar. Rounder buttons.
| * bbf12b3 Add MathJax LaTeX sitewide.
| * 6629128 Customize register form and add email activation.
| * 27f7114 FEATURE - Add basic search to navbar.
```

**My attempts**

I'm not opposed to rebasing and squashing if that's what I have to do. I've tried using `git rebase -i HEAD~n` but the doubling-up is not reflected in the list of commits there, so I can't.

**Question**

Can I reset the repository to an earlier state (based on a point in time)? (For reference, my repo is on GitHub.)

If nothing works, I suppose I could start the repository anew, as all functionality is preserved. It's just a messy history.

**Related question**

Please do not close as duplicate of [Fixing git double-commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817360/fixing-git-double-commit-history). While the questions are similar, the accepted answer doesn't apply to my case, as the doubled commits are not reflected in the `git rebase` file where you choose pick/squash.

Comment: Are you supplying any additional arguments to `git log`?  Also, try `git log --graph`, or `git log --oneline --decorate --graph` (adding `--graph` is often quite revealing); and also look at `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all`.

Comment: Is this reflected in the history on Github?

Comment: @torek -  `git log --graph` shows all doubled commits on the same "line" so to speak. There's no divergence. The only parts where there is divergence, is when I merged other branches into master. There are doubled commits there too.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - Yes, GitHub shows the doubling too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817360/fixing-git-double-commit-history

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - Yes, I read that. My question differs in that I cannot rebase as the list of commits in the rebase doesn't show doubling commits. Or... I guess the question is the same, but the accepted answer doesn't apply, and there are no other answers.

Comment: I'd definitely need more information to figure out what did happen and/or what to do about it.  The `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` output, for instance, might help, or (much shorter and simpler) a link to the github repo.

Comment: @torek - It's a private repo, but I can give you access. I'd really appreciate the help. What is your user?

Comment: @torek - `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` actually did NOT reflect the problem. Added output to question.

Comment: This is actually pretty interesting. I'd go as far as opening an issue with Git suspecting it's a bug. (Worst case, Linus tells you to f off)

Comment: I'd LOVE to be on the receiving end of a Linus email!

Comment: Hmm, very interesting ... if `--all` does not show the duplicated commits, what reference is bringing them in?  Without `--all`, `git log` should be using `HEAD`, but `HEAD` points to `303bbfe` (perhaps through `master`, if your git is a bit older and does not have the new `HEAD -> ...` notation) which doesn't lead to the duplicated commits  Usually this sort of duplication results from using `git filter-branch`, which does in fact copy commits, and accidentally leaving the old commits in as well.  Did you use `filter-branch`?  Are there some tags, perhaps...

Comment: @torek - Yes, I have indeed used `git filter-branch`. I used it to try and change the author of all my old user's commits to my new one. I used it as described in this guide: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/

Comment: OK, the recipe on github looks correct (has a tag name filter).  So some reference(s) still get you to the old commits, before filter-branch copied them to corrected ones.  The trick is to figure out what those references are.  The repo used for filtering keeps them in `refs/original/refs/*` so make sure you don't have any of those copied to github and/or your local repo...

Comment: I've contacted GitHub staff, who are looking into it, so I'm afraid to start tinkering for myself. I might just get in the way. I'll make an answer-post if they resolve and explain it. Alternatively, they might do it themselves, as they are aware of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is what was recommended by the GitHub team over e-mail, after about a week of investigation.*

**Cause**

At some point, I did a `git filter-branch`, after which I force-pushed (`git push -f origin`), but I neglected to rebase my local clone. On the next push, my local history was pushed on top of the remote history, causing the doubling-up of commits.

**Solution**

Sadly, there is no *quick* fix for this. The solution, as was my initial suspicion, was that there needs to be a complete rebase of all commits, whereby you `pick` and `squash` each pair of double-commits.

For this, you can use [Git's interactive rebase tool](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Reordering-Commits).

For repositories with any substantial history, this is going to be quite the task, and could be very time-consuming.

**Alternate solution**

The working tree is still in good shape, so another solution is to simply migrate the working tree to a new project.

Caution: You will lose your commit history by doing this, but let's face it, that's the goal in the first place.