# Github public repository messed up after history rewritten

Tags: git, github, open-source, git-filter-branch

We have an issue with our GitHub public repository [lyrgard/ffbeEquip](https://github.com/lyrgard/ffbeEquip) for which I am a big contributer.

Recently, the main maintainer and developer Lyrgard realized that his work email address was used in some commit information.

Hence, he followed [this helpful Github script](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/) to replace all work email by his personnal one. As such, the git history was entirely rewritten. We *know* of course this isn't something one should do lightly. But he couldn't risk having his work address being associated to his hobby project.

However, the issue is that now we have multiple past commits. Even my commits are shown twice!

The [Github script](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/) doesn't says anything about it. We tried to search the web for answers, but couldn't find anything useful. We are not expert at git, as I'm sure you have understood by now.

What we actually tried:

- Removing [all branches except master](https://gist.github.com/leoapost/4318441#gistcomment-2685361)
- Running [Git garbage-collector](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)

We would really like to understand what happened, what is the current situation, and how we can resolve it.

Thanks a lot for your help.

**[First edit to add details]**

Here is the `git log` output on master:

```
commit b2d98cb6674b0a9d2c457cdcf5bf7dc1271d87c5 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: Lyrgard <lyrgard@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 30 06:55:43 2018 +0200

    added Golden Apple to recently released items

commit 850244a19880ddcbc0637a17ab01241d6ef0133a
Merge: 362d9a14 ef8c6e12
Author: Lyrgard <lyrgard@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 30 06:53:18 2018 +0200

    Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/lyrgard/ffbeEquip

commit 362d9a1409470bd498e5787daa7817400aedd5f1
Merge: 99618a7e 1bca87ad
Author: Lyrgard <lyrgard@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Aug 29 23:04:46 2018 +0200

    Merge branch 'Indigo744-encyclopedia_killers'

commit ef8c6e125e6d76d04a0fe28e74fce5439bc4f9f2
Merge: 09722cee 8c1b8394
Author: Lyrgard <lyrgard@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Aug 29 23:04:46 2018 +0200

    Merge branch 'Indigo744-encyclopedia_killers'

commit 1bca87ad243079e0df0599a8e8e414b75b580f68
Merge: 99618a7e 4ce21f1e
Author: Lyrgard <lyrgard@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Aug 29 23:02:28 2018 +0200

    Merge branch 'encyclopedia_killers' of https://github.com/Indigo744/ffbeEquip into Indigo744-encyclopedia_killers

commit 8c1b83944ade8dbc1eaf1576df00c8e4c46a051b
Merge: 09722cee 5fc10187
Author: Lyrgard <lyrgard@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Aug 29 23:02:28 2018 +0200

    Merge branch 'encyclopedia_killers' of https://github.com/Indigo744/ffbeEquip into Indigo744-encyclopedia_killers
```

As you can see, there are two `Merge branch 'Indigo744-encyclopedia_killers'` and two `Merge branch 'encyclopedia_killers' of...`

Of course, the commit sha are not equals (otherwise, there would be a huge issue I think) but I can't understand why is there multiple commits?

**[Second edit to add more details on *what* happened]**

After discussins with @matthiasbe in the comments, and carefully reviewing the git branch (and discussing with Lyrgard), here what actually happened:

1. He cloned the repo into a clean temp one
2. He use the github script `filter-branch` on this repo to rewrite history
3. He pushes the whole new history to GitHub.
4. Delete temp repo. *Right now, everything is fine*
5. Went to bed. Next morning, go to his usual repo, pull the changes from Github
6. Work a bit on it, commit and pushes to Github. *this is actually where it is no longer fine*

Now the GH has two history (old and new) because, in the second (usual) repo, he should have rebase or delete and clone a new one.

**Now that we know what happened, we need to be able to revert this merge from the history**

I am looking at `rebase -i` command but I can't find any merging commit. More help woud be appreciated.

Comment: `the issue is that now we have multiple past commits` I don't get how this is possible, sorry. DO you have any idea ? Do you have several identical past commits on your `git log` command ?

Comment: Well, have a look here: https://github.com/lyrgard/ffbeEquip/commits/master and you'll see. I may add more details to the post

Comment: According to the *note* given on the page of the script your used, every collaborator have to pull the repo *as is* without merging, or pushing your local changes. To me this might come from someone pull / pushing the old history whereas it was rewritten by the script.
This my explanation, it doesn't help solving it :p

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817360/fixing-git-double-commit-history) I think they had the same issue as you have and came to the same conclusion

Comment: I think you may be right. It seems that the culprit is [this commit](https://github.com/lyrgard/ffbeEquip/commit/850244a19880ddcbc0637a17ab01241d6ef0133a) where Lyrgard merge a master branch into... itself? This is where the history starts being duplicated...

Comment: Yes this looks like someone merging a remote rewritten project into the local version, merging everything (commits are duplicated because they have a different hash after branch-filter) and pushing back to repo. I'm afraid I don't know a quick solution for this. using the solution from the thread I linked would be very time-consuming as you have a lot of duplicated commits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, everything went back to normal.

What actually saved us is that Lyrgard still had the temporary repository he used to for the `filter-branch`. It was a "clean" repo, meaning with only the new history, but dated from yesterday (i.e. missing today's commits).

What we did:

1. Saved each new commits of the day (they were 3 commits) in separate patch files.
2. Clone the temp "clean" repo into another one
3. Apply the patch and commit each time (with same message)
4. Force push this repo to Github. GitHub now is clean.
5. Remove all other local repositories
6. Clone from Github

At last... Thanks [matthiasbe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6400167/matthiasbe) for the help.